# Out-file , txt are created , no data saved

Tags: powershell, logging, txt

```
$session = New-PSSession Comp1,Comp2,Comp3

Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\' -Force -Filter "example" }

Select-Object LastWriteTime | Out-file -Path \\log.com\log\\log.txt
```

I am running this script on my DC. The txt file was created , but this Zero data inside the file. Same thing with export-csv. I don't think file share is the problem. PLS help

Comment: You’re missing a connecting pipe to your Select-Object

Comment: I don't know what connecting pipe is

Comment: he means this: `Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {

Get-ChildItem 'C:\Program Files\' -Force -Filter "example" | Select-Object LastWriteTime}`

Comment: you can also just invoke the command on an array without creating a pssession for them. `$MyArray = @("Comp1","Comp2","Comp3") 
invoke-command -ComputerName $MyArray -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Program Files' -Force -Filter "Example" | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime}`

Comment: or... you can simply specify the UNC path for the machines like so: `Get-ChildItem -Path "\\$MyArray\C$\Program Files" -Force -Filter "Example" | Select-Object -Property LastWriteTime`